# UK student visa refusal

Tags: united-kingdom, student-visa, refusal

I was recently refused twice for a Tier 4 student visa. In the first application, my step-father had provided all the required documents for proof of money. However, our connection was doubted and, therefore, I had no proof of funds.
[image]
In the second, my mother had provided savings accounts as proof of funds; the university had looked through it all and provided me with a second CAS. Again, this was refused, on the grounds that apparently 6-8 of the accounts have already been used for another UK tier 4 visa. This makes no sense considering that this was my mother and the money was in savings account for my benefit.
We did not use an agent and as far as my research shows, the bank is not on the list of untrusted banks.[image]

I understand there can be an administrative review, but what are my chances of succeeding? If I were to apply again for next academic year, will my chances be hurt by these refusals?

Comment: Were any of these eight separate accounts also in those that you used first time round (i.e. when your stepfather was providing documents), and why are there eight separate accounts in the first place rather than one savings account?

Comment: @nkjt no they were not in the first application, my mother had kept them aside for my 2nd year of uni fees, and it was bank policy each time a deposit was made it could not go into the same account as there was set interest (or sth along those lines)

Comment: Is it at all possible that a relative or other person used those account numbers for an application?

Comment: @nkjt Not that I would know of, and the money was saved for me for this exact purpose. Should we ask for admin review?