# Can I get NL Student visa after UK visa refusal?

Tags: netherlands, student-visa, uk-visa, refusal

After trying and being refused twice for tier 4 visa in the UK, both on finance reasons, my plight can be read about here ([UK student visa refusal](https://expatriates.stackexchange.com/questions/9283/uk-student-visa-refusal))
I'm looking at applying to university else where in Europe, and the Netherlands have a couple universities that I like. Will it be a problem for me if I declare everything and is truthful on my application form?

Answer (score 2):

The UK refusals should not be a problem of themselves.  The most likely possibility is that the circumstances you showed to the UK, which were inadequate and resulted in a refusal, will also be inadequate for the requirements of the Netherlands, and will therefore result in a refusal there as well.

On the other hand, it's possible that the Netherlands evaluates such circumstances differently, and might therefore accept your application.

Above all, you should not try to hide your history with the UK.  You will very likely be found out, and a visa refusal for deception will make it difficult for you to get a visa *anywhere* for a very long time, perhaps for the rest of your life.

Your experience with the UK shows that your financial situation is complicated, and that your applications were not always optimally prepared (in particular, you didn't always have a full understanding of the rules governing your application).  You are likely to have a better shot at approval if you hire a reputable professional to prepare the application.

You should most likely look for an immigration lawyer *in the Netherlands* rather than an agent in your home country, since we have heard many stories of such agents being unscrupulous, or at least insufficiently familiar with the rules of the foreign country with which the visa application is being filed.  For a local lawyer, the country isn't foreign, and the lawyer is a specialist in the law of that country.

Comment: By the time of application of Netherlands visa I will 18 and be able to have my parents transfer the money into a bank account in my name. Will that help the situation? as I no longer need to prove the association or anything like that. The money was always there and ready to use, the only problem we seemed to have was showing that I had access to it. @phoog

Comment: @A.Ren I think you have misinterpreted your refusal notices. All the more reason to get professional assistance.